# Elisp - How to run a shell command and make buffer to be in markdown-mode?

Tags: shell, emacs

```
(defun jira-view-git-branch ()
  (interactive)
  (markdown-mode)
  (shell-command (format "./jira-view.sh &")))
```

So how to make the output buffer to be in markdown mode?

I tried the following

```
(defun jira-view-git-branch ()
  (interactive)
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*jira*"
    (shell-command (format "./jira-view.sh &") "*jira*" "*Messages*")
    (pop-to-buffer "*jira*"))
  (with-current-buffer "*jira*"
    (markdown-mode)))
```

but got this in *Messages*

```
error in process filter: read-from-minibuffer: Wrong type argument: markerp, nil
error in process filter: Wrong type argument: markerp, nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what your shell command `jira-view.sh` does exactly, I find it hard to come up with a good solution for this.

At least, the following should give you some pointers:

```
(defun jira-md (buffer)
  (interactive "Bbuffer name: ")
  (let ((b (get-buffer-create buffer)))
    (switch-to-buffer b)
    (markdown-mode)
    (insert (shell-command-to-string "echo '# title'"))))
```

- You can ask for a (possibly not yet existing) buffer when calling this function by having `B` be the first character in the argument to `interactive`
- Once you have a buffer name, you can switch to that buffer and then set the major mode.
- You could also make the setting of major mode optional by first examining if the major mode is not already set to markdown-mode. Something like:

  ```
  (unless (eq major-mode 'markdown-mode)
    (markdown-mode))
  ```